Create Markdown/Txt from JPG using Google Vision API TEXT_DETECTION
I'm using the Google Vision API's TEXT_DETECTION feature to extract text from images. The API returns JSON containing various bounding boxes with fragmented text, especially when the source is a photo, resulting in numerous scattered text boxes. I'm currently invoking the API with the following command:
gcloud ml vision detect-text ./path/to/local/file.jpg

More details on the API can be found here: Google Cloud Vision OCR Documentation.
Despite exploring Google's "Vision API" or "Document AI", I haven't found any built-in features or insights on how to compile these fragments into a cohesive text or markdown file.
I wondered on the possibility of leveraging open-source tools designed for generating text files from image data, possibly adapting them to use the output from Google Vision's TEXT_DETECTION instead of relying on solutions like Tesseract.
Question: Is there an existing tool, script, or library—preferably one that runs on Linux and can be utilized via Bash, Rust, or Python—that can convert the JSON output from Google Vision API TEXT_DETECTION into a readable text or markdown file?
Alternatives involving other APIs or tools are also welcome.
What I've Tried:

Executing the gcloud ml vision detect-socialist ./path/to/local/file.jpg command to detect text.
Reviewed the Google Vision and Document AI documentation for potential solutions.

I'm looking for a more streamlined way to convert these JSON outputs into a consolidated markdown or text document. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated?

HI , could you please share some images about how you are getting those images output and how you expect it should be ?

Currently all examples I used and have at hand were not to share publicly, I will look later if I can make some examples sharable. However, what's going on is simple, instead of word "Microorganisms" , if photographed page is bended a bit and photographed on engle you may get boxes like: "Mic", "roo" "rga" "n" "i" "s" "ms" ... however in close proximity obviously.  Then you want basically a way to group those boxes in close proximity into words and sentences that make sense. (and I find it even more challanging as some things I work with have tables, but that's on a top of it)

HI , as you want group all those boxes to a single meaningful word , can you refer this stackpost  Grouping text extracted as full words  , Let me know if this helps or not .

[tag:vision-api] is a useless tag. it's name is too generic. use [tag:google-vision] for tagging.

Google-vision API - the Google mobile vision api for android provided a framework for finding objects in photos and video, not perfectly fit for cloud platform like gcp.
